# Existence of Laplace tranformation

Tags: integration, linear-transformations

How do i show if the **laplace transforms** of the following functions exist or not?
$$
t^{-\frac{3}{2}},
\\
t^{-\frac{1}{2}},
\\
e^{t^2}.
$$
Thank you.

Comment: Have you studied improper integrals? For each try and write down the (integral) definition of Laplace transform and see whether it converges or not for fixed $s$.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Math SE! It is likely that the answer to your question is already present : you can use the search engine [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) to search for your question. You can search for mathematical expressions using this engine. For example, when I type Laplace and `$t^{-3/2}$` into the search box, I get the answer from one of the results, see [here](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3Alaplace%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24t%5E%7B-%5Cfrac%7B3%7D%7B2%7D%7D%24&p=1). It is very likely that what you ask for is already on the site.